# Traversing json array in python

Tags: python, json, django, urllib

I'm using urllib.request.urlopen to get a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "76972": {
            "pageid": 76972,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Title",
            "thumbnail": {
                "original": "https://linktofile.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant code to get the response:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com?title="+object.title)
data = response.read()
encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
json_object = json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value of "original", but I'm having a hard time getting there.
I can do `print(json_object['query']['pages']` but once I do `print(json_object['query']['pages'][0]` I run into a KeyError: 0.

How would I be able to, with python retrieve the value of `original`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
my_content = json_object['query']['pages']['76972']['thumbnail']['original']
```

The reason is, you need to mention `index` as `[0]` only when you have list as the object. But in your case, every item is of `dict` type. You need to specify `key` instead of `index`

If number is dynamic, you may do:

```
page_content = json_object['query']['pages']
for content in page_content.values():
    my_content = content['thumbnail']['original']
```

where `my_content` is the required information.

Comment: The number is dynamic, so I - sadly - cannot do this.

Comment: Is this usable with python2?

Comment: Yes it is. I am using Python 2.7 and it is supported by it

Answer (score 0):

Doing `[0]` is looking for that key - which doesn't exist. Assuming you don't always know what the key of the page is, Try this:

```
pages = json_object['query']['pages']
for key, value in pages.items():  #  this is python3
    original = value['thumbnail']['original']
```

Otherwise you can simply grab it by the key if you do know (what appears to be) the `pageid`:

```
json_object['query']['pages']['76972']['thumbnail']['original']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over keys:

```
for page_no in json_object['query']['pages']:
    page_data = json_object['query']['pages'][page_no]
```